# Is it possible to draw a bar and arrow/pointer on the right side of a chart?

Tags: chart.js

I currently have [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N97mO.png) chart.

I'm attempting to create something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ucH8x.png).

The bar on the side is static, but the section "heights" need to be programmable when the page loads. I attempted encoding in an SVG but I wasn't able to get it to stick to the chart.
I've got no clue how to make the final (current value) node to appear as an arrow pointing to the bar (or alternatively, as just a horizontal bar across the vertical one).

I made a [sample codepen](https://codepen.io/grphine/pen/gOWpgVv) to simulate the dynamic chart I currently have.

(Or, per StackOverflow's requirements, the JS code used: )

```
var randoms = [...Array(11)].map(e=>~~(Math.random()*11));
var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart");
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'line',
    data: {
        labels: randoms,
        datasets: [{
            label: 'value',
            data: randoms
        }]
    },
    options: {
      scales: {
        y: {
          grace: 10,
        }
      }
    }
});

function populate(){
  let temp = ~~(Math.random()*11);
  myChart.data.datasets[0].data.shift();
  myChart.data.datasets[0].data.push(temp);
  
  myChart.update();
}

setInterval(populate, 10000);
```

Any general pointers are also appreciated - I'm very new to all of this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a custom plugin for this, I added padding on the right to give space for the arrow to be drawn. You can play with the multiplyer values to make the arrow bigger/smaller

Example:

```js
var randoms = [...Array(11)].map(e => ~~(Math.random() * 11));
var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart");
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    labels: randoms,
    datasets: [{
      label: 'value',
      data: randoms,
      borderColor: 'red',
      backgroundColor: 'red'
    }]
  },
  options: {
    layout: {
      padding: {
        right: 25
      }
    },
    scales: {
      y: {
        grace: 10
      }
    }
  },
  plugins: [{
    id: 'arrow',
    afterDraw: (chart, args, opts) => {
      const {
        ctx
      } = chart;
      chart._metasets.forEach((meta) => {
        let point = meta.data[meta.data.length - 1];
        ctx.save();
        ctx.fillStyle = point.options.backgroundColor;
        ctx.moveTo(point.x, (point.y - point.y * 0.035));
        ctx.lineTo(point.x, (point.y + point.y * 0.035));
        ctx.lineTo((point.x + point.x * 0.025), point.y)
        ctx.fill();
        ctx.restore();
      })
    }
  }]
});

function populate() {
  let temp = ~~(Math.random() * 11);
  myChart.data.datasets[0].data.shift();
  myChart.data.datasets[0].data.push(temp);

  myChart.update();
}

//setInterval(populate, 10000);
```

```html
<script src="https://npmcdn.com/chart.js@latest/dist/chart.min.js"></script>
<div class="myChartDiv">
  <canvas id="myChart" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
</div>
```